# Svelte-frappe-charts throws error depending on chart type

Tags: javascript, charts, svelte

i am currently working on a front-end svelte application and would like to show a statistic about certain types of categories.
I give the user the opportunity to choose which type of chart the user wants ("line", "bar", "percentage", "pie"). If the user chooses "pie" or "percentage" I get an error, but the chart displays fine. With the other two there are no problems.

This is my "Parent-page":

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import Header from '$lib/Header.svelte';
    import MainNavigator from '$lib/MainNavigator.svelte';
    import ChartTypeForm from "$lib/ChartTypeForm.svelte";
    import {latestChartType} from "../../stores.ts";
    import UserChart from "$lib/UserChart.svelte";


    let chartType: string;
    latestChartType.subscribe((value) => {
        chartType = value;
    });

</script>

<Header>
    <MainNavigator />
</Header>

<div class="columns">
    <div class="column box has-text-centered">
        <h1 class="title is-4">Analytics</h1>
        <ChartTypeForm />
        <UserChart charttype="{chartType}"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my ChartTypeForm (Here the user can choose the chart type):

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import {latestChartType, latestRoute} from "../stores.ts";
    import {goto} from "$app/navigation";


    let charttypes = ["bar", "line", "percentage", "pie"];

    let selectedchart = "";
    function getChartType() {
        if(selectedchart != ""){
            console.log(selectedchart);
            latestChartType.update(() => selectedchart);
        }
    }

</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={getChartType}>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column has-text-centered">
            <label for="charttype" class="title is-5">Charttype:</label>
            <div class="select">
                <select bind:value={selectedchart} id="charttype">
                    {#each charttypes as chart}
                        <option>{chart}</option>
                    {/each}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="control">
                    <button class="button is-link is-light">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my UserChart (here i get the data from my api and display it in the charts):

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import Chart from "svelte-frappe-charts";
    import { onMount, afterUpdate } from "svelte";
    import { KASDMapsService } from "../services/KASD-Maps-service.ts";

    let analytics: object = {
        userCount: 0,
        placemarkCount: 0,
        soccerFieldCount: 0,
        worldWonderCount: 0,
        riverCount: 0,
        bridgeCount: 0,
        townCount: 0,
        cityCount: 0,
        forestCount: 0,
        landscapeFeatureCount: 0,
        nationalMonumentCount: 0,
        walkingTrailCount: 0,
        treeCount: 0,
        entertainmentVenueCount: 0,
        islandCount: 0,
        archaeologicalFeatureCount: 0,
        othersCount: 0
    };
    onMount( async () => {
        analytics = await KASDMapsService.getAnalytics();
        data.datasets[0].values[0] = analytics.userCount;
        data.datasets[0].values[1] = analytics.placemarkCount;

        data2.datasets[0].values[0] = analytics.soccerFieldCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[1] = analytics.worldWonderCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[2] = analytics.riverCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[3] = analytics.bridgeCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[4] = analytics.townCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[5] = analytics.cityCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[6] = analytics.forestCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[7] = analytics.landscapeFeatureCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[8] = analytics.nationalMonumentCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[9] = analytics.walkingTrailCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[10] = analytics.treeCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[11] = analytics.entertainmentVenueCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[12] = analytics.islandCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[13] = analytics.archaeologicalFeatureCount;
        data2.datasets[0].values[14] = analytics.othersCount;
    });


    let data = {
        labels: ["Users", "Placemarks"],
        datasets: [
            {
                values: [0 ,0]
            }
        ]
    };

    let data2 = {
        labels: ["Soccer-field", "World-wonder", "River", "Bridge", "Town", "City", "Forest", "Landscape-feature", "National-monument", "Walking-Trail", "Tree", "Entertainment-Venue", "Island", "Archaeological-Feature", "Others"],
        datasets: [
            {
                values: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
            }
        ]
    };

     export let charttype; // TODO ts


</script>
<div>
    <div class="column box m-4">
        <h1 class="title is-4">Users to date | Placemarks to date</h1>
        <Chart data={data} type={charttype}  />
    </div>
    <div class="column box m-4">
        <h1 class="title is-4">Placemarks Types to date</h1>
        <Chart data={data2} type={charttype} />
    </div>
</div>
```

This are the errors I get after loading the site once with the "pie" chart and once with the "percentage" chart:
[image]

Comment: Since the Svelte code can't be run in the code snippets, just use normal code blocks instead and inside a component better use a store value directly with the `$` prefix instead of using `update/subscribe` https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values Did you have a look at the values you get from the api if they are all valid or does the problem persist with dummy values? Simple rebuild seems to be working fine https://www.sveltelab.dev/zwhplugkt49cqoz